# Clang cindex can't find header in unsaved_files

Tags: python, clang

I'm trying to use `clang.cindex` in Python, but when I try to pass in a dummy header, it doesn't work:

```
import sys
from clang import cindex
tu = cindex.Index.create().parse('t.cc', args=[], unsaved_files=[
    ('t.h', ''),
    ('t.cc', '#include "t.h"'),
])
for diag in tu.diagnostics:
    sys.stderr.write(diag.format() + "\n")
```

The error I receive is:

```
t.cc:1:10: fatal error: 't.h' file not found
```

What is going on? Why can it find `t.cc` but not `t.h`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is due to the lack of a `./` prefix. Apparently paths aren't canonicalized.

This works fine:

```
import sys
from clang import cindex
tu = cindex.Index.create().parse('./t.cc', args=[], unsaved_files=[
    ('./t.h', ''),
    ('./t.cc', '#include "t.h"'),
])
for diag in tu.diagnostics:
    sys.stderr.write(diag.format() + "\n")
```